# Will Node.js stand up to high velocity and high concurrency outside of web use cases?

Tags: node.js, performance, events

I've been working on a project where I'm only given a choice between Node and Python due to library support, and since the Node support is better and I don't particularly care for either language (or any of their respective derivatives), I chose Node.js for my project.

I thought this would shake out nicely. This component is a resource monitor, effectively organized like an actor system from Erlang or Scala: there is an independent "ticking" state machine for each resource that checks status, makes I/O requests, sorts and processes incoming data streams, and changes state as a result.

So it's a highly concurrent system that's mostly I/O-bound but also has a meaningful chunk of CPU-heavy work.

I realize opinions aren't allowed here, but there's literally nowhere on the Internet where the rules allow me to ask this professional opinion of my peers, which I find insane. So I'll try anyway.

My question is: will Node.js be able to stand up to this task? I know it's single-threaded with an event loop running the show. Is it smart enough to avoid resource starvation or the other pitfalls of that model? Should I expect this thing to handle lots of concurrent monitors, or should I expect to need to horizontally scale this thing a lot?

My thinking is I can take a lot of the logic out and move it into a Go program that takes care of sensible load balancing and also alleviates some of the pressure on the Node event loop, but I'm trying to get a sense of where in the roadmap that will fall.

TIA for any flexibility you can have with the rules. I think we as a community have a bit of PTSD from the Web2.0 spam days, and we need some opinions back in the world :)

Answer (score 0):

node.js can pretty much be adapted to do anything and it is particularly good with heavy I/O related work.  If you have some heavy CPU computation, then you will want to get more CPUs involved in the work.  There are a number of ways to do that, all of which are fairly straightforward.

For example, you can do plain clustering on one server using the built-in clustering module and that will let you leverage all your CPUs on that server.  The only real design change needed for that is that any data you wish to share among your server processes has to be in its own process (such as redis or some other database) so that all the clustered processes can have access to that data.  In some cases, it may be more efficient or required to use "sticky" clients that come back to the same server in the cluster each time (that depends entirely upon what you're doing).

Or, in some cases, it works better to create a work queue of the CPU-intensive work and have a series of specialized worker processes to do the CPU crunching, keeping your main process free to respond to requests and do I/O work which it is very efficient at.

In some other cases, you might even do both (have a work queue of specialized child processes and use clustering).

> My question is: will Node.js be able to stand up to this task?

Yes, if you design it appropriately.  Ultimately, you'll have to implement, test, measure and make design changes to adapt to what you learn.

> I know it's single-threaded with an event loop running the show. Is it smart enough to avoid resource starvation or the other pitfalls of that model?

I'm not really sure what you mean by "resource starvation".  The event loop model works very well and very efficiently with code that does some work, then some I/O, then some work, then some I/O, then returns a result as long as the "some work" doesn't take too much CPU.  A node.js server can handle lots of simultaneous requests very efficiently with this model (more efficiently than threaded models).  If you do have heavier CPU work, then to achieve higher scale, you need to involve more CPUs as described above.

> Should I expect this thing to handle lots of concurrent monitors, or should I expect to need to horizontally scale this thing a lot?

As I've already said, if you have CPU-intensive work, you will want to at least involve all the CPUs on your server (as you would need to do with any programming environment).  Depending upon how much computation you're talking about, you might also need to scale your servers themselves horizontally.  You will need to build a non-horizontally scaled implementation first and then do some scaling tests to see if you need scale further or not.  As with any server-side problem in any server-side environment, you can't fully predict where your bottlenecks are going to be.  The best approach when you know your shooting for high scale is to design something that will be able to be horizontally scaled with further development, but implement your first server and test where your bottlenecks are, fix those bottlenecks, iterate and so on.  Designing and implementing far ahead of any real world testing is also a mistake as you may be working on the wrong problems.  This stuff is not entirely easy to predict before you've tested actual code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your very thoughtful response. I suppose I made a major design mistake when I included the CPU-heavy tasks in cascading promises. That leads me to this weird situation I'm in now where it seems the event loop queue is filling up quite a bit at times, causing other spontaneous timeouts/failures. Unfortunate thing is there is some shared state that can't be easily represented in Redis et al. I'll see what I can do with the built-in clustering module. Thanks again!

Comment: @William - Did this answer your question?  Moving the CPU intensive part out to a child process will indeed help with event loop responsiveness.  Clustering will also help.  The best design if you have lots of CPU-intensive stuff would be no create a work queue for the CPU-intensive stuff and a set of workers to service the queue.  Then, you can keep all the CPU intensive stuff away from the event loop and you build yourself some control over the CPU intensive stuff so you just put N of those in flight at the same time with the workers (where N is how many CPUs you have).